# How to click a checkbox in an alert popus using Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

guys
I cannot find a solution of the clicking (unclicking) a checkbox placed in an alert window, modal pop-ups.
We have three types pop-up: alert, confirm, prompt. 
In the confirm popup there is a checkbox. I want to check it using selenium webdriver and java language.
There are functions handling these popups: dismiss(), accept(), sendKeys(), getText(). 
Is it possible to check the checkbox in  popups? I hope, it's. 
Could anybody help me? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two ways

1)

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
```

Put your locator in above code

2)

If above doesn't work then as below:

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window

driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
```

If even that doesn't work check if there is any frame present, you need to switch to frame also

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
But there is a problem:
In both example you use the 'xPath'. But it's not possible to a xPath locator in an Alert Popup field. So your suggestions dont resolve the problem. Maybe i am wrong...  
There are four functions handling the alert popup: accept(), dismiss(), getText(), sendKeys(). None of them makes action I expect" checking a checkbox.
Maybe there are another functions.
U know?
br